# Python Playwright "CSS Selector Text" Copy & paste on an input field

Tags: python, playwright

**Hello, pretty new to StackOverflow, as well as (playwright)
The idea here is to go on a website click the element "copy" and then Paste the "coppied" Element on an input field this is how im currently doing it:**

```
page.goto("https://www.disposablemail.com/")                         
page.click("#home > div > div:nth-child(6) > div.col-xs-12.col-md-4.text-right.noPadding.noBg > ul > li.borderLeft > a") 

#copied email

ua = page.query_selector("#email"); #Email Credential
```

This is how I call the element at the moment
however it doesn't work on input when tried to.

```
print(f"{ua.inner_text()}")

page.type("input[type='text']", ua.inner_text()) # Input Email

**page.type("input[type='text']", ua.inner_text())** does not function
```

Thanks in advance

ERROR Message:

[https://i.imgur.com/i8VRnq6.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnZ0M.png)